# How can I start auto start an animation without onActive, and set the initial value for animatedFloatAsState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the past (before alpha11), I can animate a value from 0 to 1 upon triggering the composable function as below, where I can set `initialValue` and also have `onActive` with `aniumateTo`.

```
val animatedProgress = animatedFloat(0f)
onActive {
    animatedProgress.animateTo(
        targetValue = 1f,
        anim = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation =
                tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
        )
    )
}

val t = animatedProgress.value
```

However, now in alpha13, I cannot find a way to set `initialValue`, or `animateTo`. The `onActive` is also now deprecated.

I coded as below

```
    val floatAnimation = animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
        )
    )
```

How can I...

- Set initial value of 0
- Starting the animation (without needing a state boolean to kick it off)
- Animate from 0 to 1 repeatedly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**`Animatable`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable) API and the **`LaunchedEffect`** composable. You don't need a boolean to start the animation.

Something like:

```
val animatedAlpha = remember { Animatable(0f) }

Box(
    Modifier
        .background(color = (Color.Blue.copy(alpha = animatedAlpha.value)))
        .size(100.dp,100.dp)

)

LaunchedEffect(animatedAlpha) {
    animatedAlpha.animateTo(1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing)
        ))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to use a boolean to change the state and use `LaunchEffect` to start and change the state as below.

```
    var start by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }

    val floatAnimation = animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (start) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
        )
    )
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        start = true
    }

    val t = floatAnimation.value
```

Not sure if this is the best way to code around it.